# How, using jQuery, might I obtain the src attribute of a HTML img element?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

When the mouse cursor moves over an image, I would like to display an `alert()` containing the value of that image's `src` attribute. How could I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event.

If you have

```
<img src='foo.jpg' id='bar'>
```

You can have some jQuery code like

```
$('#bar').mouseover(function(){ alert($(this).attr('src')); });
```

(if this fails you could also try replacing `$(this)` with `$('#bar')`, but as noted in the comments it's pretty ugly)

edit: missed the need to display the src attribute first time through..

Comment: @chalist, sorry -- give it another go

Comment: Why not just use `this` inside the handler instead of the actual '#bar' selector?

Comment: like, `$('#bar').mouseover(function(){ alert($( this ).attr('src')); });`? Man, @Pekka is right, this is UGLY!

Comment: @Jacob, started that way, OP was getting undefined, this will for sure return the correct result. rolled it back for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
function alertSource( image ) {
   alert( image.src );
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="path/to/image" onmouseover="alertSource(this);" alt=""/>
```

You do not need jQuery for this.

Comment: you do mean onmouseover instead of onclick, no?

Comment: I've noticed that we usually answer the same types of questions, it's only a matter of who answers first. :)

Comment: How about upvoting because i had VALID html?? ( the `alt` attribute ) :)

Comment: +1 for doing it without jQuery (*despite* the OP asking for it), and for having valid HTML... =)

Comment: +1 for doing it without Jquery (which just uglifies the job horrendously. Just *look* at that code!) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="some_img.gif">
<script>
$("img").bind("mouseover",function(){
alert($(this).attr("src"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why use `bind` when you have the `mouseover` shortcut function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').mouseover(function() { 
    alert( this.src );
});
```