# Use jQuery to get src="x" value

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How, using jQuery, might I obtain the src attribute of a HTML img element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125716/how-using-jquery-might-i-obtain-the-src-attribute-of-a-html-img-element)

How can I use jQuery to fetch the SRC attribute of a  value?

Answer (score 11):

```
$(el).attr("src")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alert($("#elem").attr("src"));
```